# Autodesk Forge load multiple URNs translated from the multiple users

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have Viewer created by using my access token but I want to load the models (urns) translated come from the other users. Is it possible ? Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so three part answer:

1. For multi model loading, inside Forge Viewer, follow this guide: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7
2. Multi model loading can only use 1 Access Token.
3. If the other models were translated by other people, and the files live on ACC/BIM 360 storage, then ask for permission to be added to those projects.   Then, when you generate a 3-legged token as per the [Hubs Browser Tutorial](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/auth), your token will have permission to access files translated by other people.

For #2, you could try this trick.
Try changing the AccessToken, after each load has fully completed, by overriding the built-in token, used by LMV's Fetch command here:

ie.

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.token.accessToken = "token-user1"
await loadModel(URN_user1_Model);
await sleep(5000);

Autodesk.Viewing.Private.token.accessToken = "token-user2"
await loadModel(URN_user2_Model);
await sleep(5000);

Autodesk.Viewing.Private.token.accessToken = "token-user3"
await loadModel(URN_user3_Model);
```

It's not guaranteed to work, but you can try.